# Threading Queue and multiprocessing assistance

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, queue, python-multiprocessing

Preface:  This is my first attempt at using these tools

Context:  I have a very large file I am trying to process.  So I am attempting to break the file up into smaller chunks.  Then load those files into a queue for processing.

The goals was to speed up what is a very slow process.

Code:

```
import lifetimes
import os
import pandas
import Queue
import threading
import multiprocessing
import glob
import subprocess


#move master to processing dir
os.system("cp /data/ltv-testing1.csv /data/out")

#break master csv into 1 million row chunks
subprocess.call(['bash', '/home/ddewberry/LTV_CSV_Split.sh'])

#remove master file
os.remove("/data/out/ltv-testing1.csv")

os.chdir("/data/out")


# Create List of Files
worker_data = glob.glob('split_*')

#build queue with file list
q = Queue.Queue(worker_data)

#import tools for data processing
from lifetimes.utils import summary_data_from_transaction_data

#define worker for threads

def worker(outfile = '/data/in/Worker.csv'):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        data = pandas.read_csv(item)
        summary = summary_data_from_transaction_data(data, data[[2]], data[[1]])
        summary.to_csv(outfile%s % (item))
        q.task_done()

cpus=multiprocessing.cpu_count() #detect number of cores
print("Creating %d threads" % cpus)
for i in range(cpus):
     t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

q.join()

#clean up
for row in worker_data:
    os.remove(row)
```

Problem:

I don't get any error messages however it doesn't work at all.  (It basically does nothing)

I am very confused at what I did wrong or what I need to fix.

Comment: For starters, `Queue.Queue` takes one argument `maxsize`, not an iterable, so `q.get()` will block indefinitely because there's nothing in it... Also, for this kind of problem threading will not give you much speedup.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Do you have a recommendation on what approach I could take to help expedite the process?

Comment: So I should do something like:                                                                      q = Queue.Queue()                                                                                                   for file in worker_data:                                                                                                   q.put(file)

Comment: That should work, but I'd recommend you have a look into [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), when using a Pool.map or similar you don't need to deal with queues etc...

Comment: Mata - Thank you very much for the suggestion.  I will explore that solution, appreciate the guidance

Comment: Hi, have you made this work? I have a very similar problem and can't get pandas to work with threads, but it that code works, I would assume mine should also work. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have gotten this code to work just fine.  What I did for Pandas to work with threading is break the file up using pandas and then load it into the queue for processing.  It worked very well for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import lifetimes
import os
import pandas
import Queue
import threading
import multiprocessing
import glob
import subprocess


#move master to processing dir
os.system("cp /data/ltv-testing1.csv /data/out")

#break master csv into 1 million row chunks
subprocess.call(['bash', '/home/ddewberry/LTV_CSV_Split.sh'])

#remove master file
os.remove("/data/out/ltv-testing1.csv")

os.chdir("/data/out")


# Create List of Files
worker_data = glob.glob('split_*')

# rename to csv
for row in worker_data:
    os.rename(row, row+'.csv')

worker_data1 = glob.glob('split_*')

#build queue with file list
q = Queue.Queue()
for files in worker_data1:
    q.put(files)
```